# Storing Eclipse Launch Configurations in Git

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, esp-idf

I'm building out some embedded tooling using the Espressif ESP-IDE (mostly based on Eclipse-CDT set up to use their toolchain). I've got enough run and debug configurations that I'd like to be able to check into git alongside the rest of the project, but as far as I can tell, these are stored as part of the eclipse workspace, not the project.

I considered storing the eclipse workspace in my project git repository, but it's the largest directory by far, and a lot of things change often like local-history, so I don't think I want to store the whole workspace in git. I built out a .gitignore, but often git-clean now breaks the Eclipse workspace, then I need to close eclipse and reset the repo to get it to load again.

Is it possible to extract just the *.launch files and store them in a project, so that the workspace finds them on import? Or is there another, better solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, open the Launch Configuration dialog and check the **Common** tab on the configuration for its option to save it as a "Shared file". The filename will be based on the name you gave the launch configuration, so you'll only get to pick which project to store it in.